# Outlook - How to find auto-complete list of emails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, autocomplete

When you type an email address in a new message in Outlook, it auto-completes from a list of emails you previously wrote too.
Where can I find this list of emails\users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook builds this list over time as you send and receive email. Names are stored in `.nk2` files, which are binary files and cannot be edited simply using a text editor. There is, however, a tool which can edit these files called [Nk2Edit](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html), which is *completely free for personal use at your home*.

Depending on your Office version, these files are stored in different places, as described [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nk2_file_location.html).